# Problems with MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given format dataset:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fc97d1e2d32371003e27"),
    "subFolder" : "notes_inbox",
    "mailbox" : "bass-e",
    "filename" : "450.",
    "headers" : {
        "X-cc" : "",
        "From" : "michael.simmons@enron.com",
        "Subject" : "Re: Plays and other information",
        "X-Folder" : "\\Eric_Bass_Dec2000\\Notes Folders\\Notes inbox",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding" : "7bit",
        "X-bcc" : "",
        "To" : "eric.bass@enron.com",
        "X-Origin" : "Bass-E",
        "X-FileName" : "ebass.nsf",
        "X-From" : "Michael Simmons",
        "Date" : "Tue, 14 Nov 2000 08:22:00 -0800 (PST)",
        "X-To" : "Eric Bass",
        "Message-ID" : "<6884142.1075854677416.JavaMail.evans@thyme>",
        "Content-Type" : "text/plain; charset=us-ascii",
        "Mime-Version" : "1.0"
    }
}
```

What I need - to display the shortest subject of the letter.
What I did:

```
db.getCollection('mails').aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$headers"},
{$group: {_id : "$_id", Subject : {$min :{$min : "$headers.Subject"}}}}
])
```

Output is almost correct, but i need ONLY one letter with shortest subject, but right now I have multiple outputs, but I need only one, the shortest:

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fe39d1e2d3237107e52d"),
    "Subject" : "RE: CONFIDENTIAL"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fe39d1e2d3237107e52c"),
    "Subject" : "Gas Hedges"
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: $min - compares the field/fields of documents within the same group where all documents share the same key. So What ever query you have written will not work, because you are grouping by _id, so each group will have only one document.
So actually you are getting all the data in your DB.
So try to group by mailbox or what ever field under which you are comparing the letters.
And one more thing the $min uses binary comparison for Strings, so you will get minimum using binary comparison.
I'm not sure what exactly is the shortest subject in your context?

Comment: I highly guess that the shortest subject means the shortest subject field string

Comment: shortest subject field string - means shortest in length of the string right? Below answer works for that

Comment: Yep, I need to find the smallest (length of the headers.Subject) letters and it should be only one, for now I still have multiple answers for every single letter -_-'

Answer (score 0):

The below query will get you the letters with shortest Subject (shortest string length)..

```
      $group: {
      _id: "$mailbox",
      length: {
        $min: {"lenth":{$strLenBytes:"$headers.Subject"},"sub":"$headers.Subject"}
      }
     }
```

Comment: Hi, ty for your answer, I got this output, but it's still multiple and for some reasons it's a bit strange:

Comment: ```{
    "_id" : "zufferli-j",
    "length" : {
        "lenth" : 0,
        "sub" : ""
    }
}```

Comment: Here what i thought was you want to compare the emails in each "mailbox" and then   get the one with shortest "subject". So in query _id:"$mailbox". 
You are not understanding the query at all.  
$group - groups based on the  field you give and then compares all the documents in that group to get $min or $max.
So if in the Database you have entities with "mailbox" - different value for mailbox then you will have those many results.